# Apple Store Hyperlink not opening

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I used **UITEXTVIEW** for displaying data and set its **dataDetectorTypes** to **UIDataDetectorTypeLink** for detecting hyperlink.
it work fine for other all hyperlink but not open **Apple store** hyperlink in web view.
what should i do to open apple store hyperlink also something like https://t.co/0BQtx1pV